# CA0001: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sonarqube, code-analysis

*Please read the question first, before flagging it as duplicate for "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"*

I run a build with SonarQube. I get the following error:

```
CA0001 : Rule=Microsoft.Design#CA1011, Target=Company.Project.Service.Report.Wrappers.Helper.ReportPrintingOrderDriver`2.#DrivePrintingProcess(Company.Product.Service.Contracts.Report.CommonExportReportRequest,Company.Project.Common.Containers.LIHierarchy`3<!0,!1,System.Int32>,Company.Project.Service.Report.Wrappers.Helper.ReportPrintingOrderDriver`2<!0,!1>+IReportPrintingOrderDriven) : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The error happens since I turned on NDepend Analysis in SonarQube. 
I tried excluding the File from Analysis by adding it to the Source File Exclusions in the SonarQube Analysis scope. When that did not work, I added a exclusion into the csproj file:

```
<Compile Include="Wrappers\Helper\ReportPrintingOrderDriver.cs" >
        <!-- Exclude the file from analysis -->
       <SonarQubeExclude>true</SonarQubeExclude>
</Compile>
```

But unfortunately, the error still keeps popping up. When I run the Visual Studio Code Analysis for the project, the same error appears. So I think it has nothing to do with NDepend. After turning off all the NDepend rules, the error still fails the build.

NDepend Support referred me to the following [WebSite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245246.aspx)

The class that it cannot analyse starts like this:

```
public class ReportPrintingOrderDriver<TInnerNode, TDataNode> where TDataNode : IComparable<TDataNode>, IMergeable<TDataNode>
    {
      ...
    }
```

Any suggestions how to get rid of this error?

Comment: From the linked page: "If that does not work, contact Microsoft Product Support Services."

Comment: I sent them a Frown from Visual Studio discribing the problem.

Comment: I did some more research. It turns out there is already an active issue about this analysis error: [Issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/799960/static-analysis-failure-with-interfaces-defined-into-generic-types).
The linked issue contains an Attachment which reproduces the problem.
I can confirm that the issue seem to be with interface defined into generic types.
When I moved the interface to outside of the generic type, the error disappeared.

Comment: you probably can answer your own question then: this indeed seems to be a bug from an FxCop rule, and unrelated to NDepend and SonarQube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a way to fix this error. But there is a workaround. It is a known issue of the Microsoft Code Analysis that occurs, when a generic class contains and uses an interface. The issue can be found on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/799960/static-analysis-failure-with-interfaces-defined-into-generic-types). The linked issue contains an Attachment which reproduces the problem.

The workaround is to extract the interface and define it outside of the generic class.